# How do I solve the below problem without reverse engineering the sample test cases

Tags: python, string, algorithm, binary-string

I solved the problem below Binary String Problem in Hackerearth the problem which says "Given four integers x,y,a and b. Determine if there exists a binary string having x 0's and y 1's such that the total number of sub-sequences equal to the sequence "01" in it is a and the total number of sub-sequences equal to the sequence "10" in it is b." " with the following code reverse engineering the sample test cases:

```
import sys
s = sys.stdin.read()

for i in s.split('\n'):
    string = i.split(' ')
    if len(string) != 4:
        print('')
    else:
        x,y,a,b = string
        x = int(x)
        y = int(y)
        a = int(a)
        b = int(b)

        if (x*y == a+b):
            print('Yes')
        else:
            print('No')
```

The explanation provided in the editorial which if x*y==a+b, then it's such a binary string exists, which I had also figured out reverse engineering the test cases but I really could not how the condition satisfies.

One of the sample cases given is x, y, a and b are 3, 2, 4 and 2 respectively, for which string 00110 is a valid string because 3*2=4+2.

But ** 00110 has 01 & 10 how is it having  so the number of 01 is not equal to "a" and number of 10 is not equal to "b". Is there any logic or any other side to the problem which I'm missing out?**

You can refer to actual Problem [**link**](https://www.hackerearth.com/pt-br/practice/python/getting-started/numbers/practice-problems/algorithm/binary-sequence-dbaf9d61/) for further details

Comment: Not sure if this would result in a copyright violation but I really was keen on understanding the actual issue here. I can delete the question if that helps.

Comment: Edited based on your suggestion. Thanks. :)

Comment: They are talking about subsequences, not slices. The `01` _subsequence_ appears in `00110` 4 times: `0x1xx, 0xx1x, x01xx, x0x1x`.

Comment: Thanks mate.. Now I get it. This means when input is 3 2 4 2, so x=3, y=2 a=4, b=2.
Number  of **10**(b) sub-sequences in `00110` is **2**, `xxx10` `xx1x0` &
Number **01**(a) sub-sequences in `00110` is **4**, `x01x` `0x1xx` `x0x1x` `x01xx`
And x*y=a+b as, 3*2=4+2